# Laravel Compact()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an interesting question, about compact in PHP and compact in Laravel.

Take this example in compact in PHP:

```
$banana = "yellow";
$apple = "red";
$result = compact('banana','apple');
var_dump($result);
//Output  
array(2) {
["banana"]=>
string(6) "yellow"
["apple"]=>
string(3) "red"
}
```

But when I use compact on controller in laravel to return to view, it return in variable not in array

```
public function fruisColor($banana="yellow",$apple="red"){
  return view('template.fruits',compact('banana','apple'));
}
```

But when I get this variable in template blade, it is not an array it is a variable, look:

```
P1 = {{ $banana }} e P1 = {{ $apple }}
```

If PHP compact convert to variables to array, why in template blade it is returning just var?
It is not should be:

```
P1 = {{ $banana[0] }} e P1 = {{ $apple[0] }}
```

Seems confusing no?

Comment: You're passing an array to the view engine, which is where your view files are being loaded/parsed and the array with data either gets unpacked into separate variables, using something like [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), or they parse the variables and replace them from some stack. Using `compact()` is just a time saver from creating the array you pass in manually.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two-argument of view method accepts an array that, according to the documentation, converts it to a variable that you can use in the blade template, Laravel can handle the array returned from the compact.

Comment: But if compact return ARRAY, laravel should just print it using foreach. Since compact return array, no?

Comment: Sure but the Laravel framework converts this array to the variable you use it in the blade. if you want to pass the array and use foreach you should give one of variable type array

Answer (score 0):

It just the way Laravel view templates handles array;

Laravel view template handle the array and makes it possible to call your data with the array key.

It does not mean it was not passed as an array with the use of compact.
Your solution could also work like this

```
 // In view
 Hello, {{ $banana }} {{$apple}}

//controller
 public function fruisColor($banana="yellow",$apple="red"){
   return view('template.fruits',['banana'=>"yellow", 'apple' => "red" ]);
}
```